# How to make setContentView() work properly with a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have 2 layouts, and 2 activities, each one corresponding to a layout, one of them is SplashActivity, and the other is MainActivity. I want the application to open the splashActivity(splash XML shows the logo), wait for 5 seconds and open the main activity, but because of the thread, the setContentView doesn't work properly.

P.S. Also any relative documentation links would be very useful, thanks in advance

> @Override
>
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
>
> ```
>     Thread timer = new Thread() {
>         public void run() {
>             try {
>                 sleep(5000);
>             } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
>                 ex.printStackTrace();
>             }
>
>             try {
>                 Class mainMenu = Class.forName("com.carmine.project.MenuActivity");
>                 Intent openMainMenu = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, mainMenu);
>                 startActivity(openMainMenu);
>             } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>         }
>     };
>
>     timer.run();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is that you are calling  `timer.run();` instead of  `timer.start();`

`timer.run();` calls the run method on the same context of the thread that executed that line (making the UI Thread, in your case, wait for 5s, and blocking every other operation).  `timer.start()` spawns a new thread