# How to call run method inside a thread from another method in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to make an quiz application in which the questions will be displayed every ten seconds. But when the user answers the question, I need to display the next question. For this I use threads. I have accomplished displaying questions in regular intervals, but when the user answers the question, it wait for the thread to complete. I want to stop the thread and start a fresh one on a button click. My code is given below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (i++ < 10) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          //Display questions here
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(6000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
public void buttonOnClick(View view) 
{
  //I want to display new question here

}
```

How can I call the run method inside the thread. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: paste thread code in your button click

Comment: check this awnser from other post and see if it helps you

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24823717/3419242

Comment: @Ajith Radhakrishnan : Try to do same thing with Timer..!! I have implemented with timer..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use t.interrupt() to stop the thread. Here is the code.

```
Thread t ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  generateQuestions()
}

public void generateQuestions()
{
   t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       int i = 0;
       try {
         while (i++ < 10 & !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      //Display questions here
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(6000);              
        }
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
  });
  t.start();
}

public void buttonOnClick(View view) 
{
  //I want to display new question here
  t.interrupt();
  generateQuestions();
}
```